# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Chrome but not in Chromium or Firefox

Tags: certificates, chrome

I'm getting a `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` for the following google sponsored website: https://viz.mediapipe.dev/

```
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Subject: mediapipe.dev
Issuer: GTS CA 1O1
Expires on: 8 Mar 2021
```

I get this in Chrome only. In both Chromium and Firefox (on Ubuntu OS) the certificate is deemed valid and the page loads without any security related warnings. How would you go about figuring whether there's a real issue or security situation v.s. just a bug in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site is improperly setup. It only serves the leaf certificate, but does not serve the necessary chain certificate for the intermediate CA "GTS CA 1O1". See [this SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=viz.mediapipe.dev&s=216.58.192.83):

[image]

Browser usually try to work around such issues, but these workarounds will not always succeed. For example an existing Firefox profile will probably have cached the missing intermediate certificates and the workaround will work. With a fresh Firefox profile it will fail though:

[image]

I'm note sure why it fails with Chrome though but still succeeds with Chromium since I would expect both to apply the same kind of workarounds. Anyways, it should be fixed on the server side since it also fails with Python, curl etc.

Comment: Great find! The fact that Firefox caches every intermediate that it sees is great for performance, but makes this kind of debugging really hard. ... *"but it works on my machine"*